# ASP.NET custom server control - making a list of radio button lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my attempt:

```
[DefaultProperty("Caption")]
    [ToolboxData("<thp:RadioButtonListList runat=server></thp:RadioButtonListList>")]
    public class RadioButtonListList : WebControl
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Caption
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Caption"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Caption"] = value;
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue(new List<RadioButtonList>())]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public List<RadioButtonList> Items
        {
            get
            {
                List<RadioButtonList> l = (List<RadioButtonList>)ViewState["Items"];
                return ((l == null) ? new List<RadioButtonList>() : l);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Items"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write("<div class=\"btn-group-vertical\" role=\"group\" aria-label=\"" + this.Caption + "\">");
            foreach (var item in this.Items) {
                item.RenderControl(output);
            }
            output.Write("</div>");
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error when I assign Items property the default value List():

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

I hope what I am trying to do here is clear... I just don't understand why I am getting this error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
[DefaultValue(new List<RadioButtonList>())]
```

`new List<RadioButtonList>()` is not a compile time constant.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions then?

Comment: You nearly have it in your getter already - instantiate it if it does not exist - amounts to the same thing.